# How to import/read an owl ontology created by protege in Jena

Tags: jena, protege, r2rml

I created an owl ontology in Protege (ontologyEx.owl). I also have rdf triples created by r2rml engine (file name is example.ttl). Is it possible to import/read ontologyEx.owl in Jena and do reasoning with my model that reads rdf triples (i.e. Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(); model.read( "example.ttl" );) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Only if ontologyEx.owl  is in the RDF syntax form for OWL. Then you need to create an "inf model".

Comment: @AndyS, Thanks for the reply. Yes ontologyEx.owl is in the RDF syntax. I am newbie in Jena. Do you mind providing a sample code on how to create an inf model? Appreciate it!!

Comment: ModelFactory.  See https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/